# Error on wakeup after installing light-locker

Tags: arch-linux, light-locker

I'm using XFCE on Arch Linux and I have Gnome installed too.
I wanted to have the possibility of locking the session so I switched to lightdm from gdm and installed light-locker. Now every time I wake my laptop from sleep by opening the lid, I get the following error notification:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.login1.OperationinProgress: There's already a shutdown or sleep operation in progress
```

`dmesg` does not reveal anything that seems related to this minor annoyance.
This is no big deal but I would like to get rid of this notification. Any ideas where to look?

Comment: It seems that the error was not necessarily due to light-locker. I uninstalled it and the issue remained. I suspect it was due to lightdm. I replaced it with gdm for another not related reason and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by running

`xfconf-query -c xfce4-power-manager -p /xfce4-power-manager/logind-handle-lid-switch -n -t bool -s true`

Source: http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-power-manager/faq